# List function not responding with a colon

Tags: python

```
y = ['h','i','j']  

def g(p):
    z = p.pop(0)
    p.extend(z)
    return p
```

These lines do not produce the same result. Why is that?

```
g(y[:]).extend(g(y))
```

Compared to

```
g(y).extend(g(y))
```

Comment: The purpose of the function makes no sense to me. Is this for curiosity?

Comment: In any case, I can assure you that `y[:]` does work.

Comment: And in what order did you run these functions? Because you're modifying `y` for every `g(y)`

Comment: In any case, your question is being downvoted because it is perceived as lazy. You are making us guess what you expected would happen and force us to run your code in order to see the two results.

Comment: These lines produce different results for y and I'm not sure why. If y and y[:] are the same surely they would both produce ['j', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'h', 'i'].

Comment: Again, care to share these results? Make sure to provide the commands you issued in exact order, preferably just copy-paste a command line session.

Comment: So the first line with the colon produces  ['j', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'h', 'i'] and the second line produces ['i', 'j', 'h']. I either of those lines and then restart the program before doing the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to the difference between using `y` and `y[:]`.

That colon in square brackets is a slice, however as you have no start or stop values, the slice is a "slice" of the *whole* list. This may seem identical to the original list, which it is, but only in *value* - behind the scenes, when you take any slice, you are given a copy of the list, not a reference to a section of it.

What this comes down to is that when you modify a *copy* of a list, the original isn't effected. Which is why when you pass a copy of `y` with `y[:]` the result changes.

---

Consider the following which should illustrate how `y` and `y[:]` are **not** the same.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> a = l
>>> b = l[:]
>>> a.append(4)
>>> b.append(5)
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 5]
>>> id(l)
140460699987208
>>> id(a)
140460699987208
>>> id(b)
140460752668680
```

Notice how modifying `a` changes `l` as they point to the same memory location (illustrated by the `id()` function). But modifying `b` does **not** modify `l` as it is a reference to a different memory location - hence the result of `id()` is different.

Answer (score 1):

`y[:]` makes a *copy* of `y`, for example:

```
>>> id(y)
140532682743688
>>> id(y[:])
140532673103944
```

so the net effect of `g(y[:]).extend(g(y))` is to rotate the list once for the copy and once on the original list. The return value of `g()` when performed on the copy is not bound to a variable so the result is lost, and the net effect is that only 1 rotation is performed on the original list.

Comment: strings are iterable, that's why it "works" for OP's `y`. :)

Comment: Thanks @timgeb, that explains it.

Comment: Ahh I get it now, cheers for that.